# How to prevent application hang during permissions check using WMI

Tags: c#, wmi

I'm using WMI, I need to get some information, but when class is not available due to insufficient permissions, everything hangs up for a few (~5) seconds. Even setting low timeout doesn't work (not to mention that it would be stupid solution).

Problem isn't insufficient permissions, problem is "hang up".

Is there any way to check if current process has privileges to read information from some class to prevent "hang up" and "access denied" exception?

```
ConnectionOptions co = new ConnectionOptions();
co.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
co.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
co.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // 1 second, but still hangs for ~5
co.EnablePrivileges = false; // false or true, doesn't matter
ManagementPath mp = new ManagementPath();
mp.NamespacePath = @"root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm";
mp.Server = "";

ManagementScope ms = new ManagementScope(mp, co);
ms.Connect(); // Hangs for ~5 seconds and throws "access denied"
```

Comment: To read all namespaces (namespace root, class __Namespaces, and than recursively for all namespaces) it takes 35 seconds. I was able to reduce it to 8 seconds, using ThreadPool (reading every child using new thread, then childs of that child again using multiple threads). It's horrible solution, but 8 is better than 35. Any ideas?

Comment: Your comment should probably be another posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is run the operation on a background thread.  It may still take five seconds (or more) but your application will remain responsive instead of hanging.  Try something like this:

```
  Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
  {
    // Your permission checking code here.....
  }).ContinueWith((t) =>
  {
    // Inform user of permissions status.
  });
```

If you aren't using a version of the framework that supports 'Task' try a BackgroundWorker instead.  These are common ways to keep long running processes from hanging your app.

Comment: I was trying to prevent hang up instead of hang background thread (which does not lower the time needed to get response), but there's no better solution probably.